# How to administrate Strategy Pattern behaviors at runtime?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm reading the [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) book when a doubt came into my head.

In the very first chapter, studying the Strategy Pattern they taught to make interchangeable classes. According to the picture below:

[image: Strategy Pattern]

My question: What if I want to make a desktop application with a visual interface and let some users have more privileges than others to administrate the Ducks and its behaviors? So, they could for example create the `FlyRocketPowered` behavior at runtime. How can I achieve this?

I mean, these behaviors look weird to me to be represented as classes, because I can't see how to make them editable at the user level, every time a `FlyBehavior`, a `QuackBehavior` or a `Duck` subclass needs to be created/deleted/changed the users will have to ask me to modify the source code by creating/deleting/changing the classes, however this not what we want, we need something more developer-independent.

**EDIT**

Say I want to make a screen `Add Fly Behavior` (just add, not edit, not remove), there would have two fields, the first would be the `Behavior Name`, the second would be the content to be printed when the `fly()` method is called.

By editing the source code I could do this by creating a class like this:

```
public class FlyRocketPowered implements FlyBehavior {
   public void fly() {
      System.out.println("I’m fl ying with a rocket!");
   }
}
```

What would I need to do to make this at the user level?

Comment: I think this is a problem which is hard to generalize with such an abstract example. First you should think how the user interface which allows users to create custom duck behaviors should work and what options it provides, and then you can think about how to represent the users design decisions on the sourcecode level. First formulate the problem, then think about the solution.

Comment: @Philipp, I tried to explain it better by editing my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly i'd like to say I love this book. It's my favourite programming book.

To your question: I think you missunderstood the strategy pattern a little bit ;)
The goal is not to enable your users to create new behaviors at runtime. But with this pattern, you can give your 'admins' some panel to give any Duck any available behavior. So the behaviors are still *generated at compiletime*. But you can *interchange the behaviors at runtime*

Additionally, just as a funfact:
It is totally possible to let your 'admin' create new Behaviors at runtime. Take a look at the [Java compiler api](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/). But if you think about doing so, remember how big the security hole is and also how unimaginable stupid the worst case customer is.

Comment: Hum.. I'm starting to think I really missed the point of the pattern, but if so, I missed the point of most of the patterns, because `programming to an interface, not an application` will eventually reach the situation where I can't edit the `behaviors` at user level.

Comment: @Math That's not a problem design patterns are meant to solve. They're about structuring your program in an understandable way, not a means to achieve personalization or directly meet some requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Strategies are instances of classes which can also have attributes. So you could create a `TextOutputFlyBehavior` class which outputs a string which can be set at runtime. Different duck-types can then receive different instances of the same Strategy class which behave the same but with different data.

```
public class TextOutputFlyBehavior implements FlyBehavior {

    private final String message;

    public TextOutputFlyBehavior(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void fly() {
         System.out.println(message);
    }
}

[...]

// some hardcoded behaviors:
FlyBehavior propellerFlyBehavior = new TextOutputFlyBehavior("I am flying with a propeller!")
FlyBehavior rocketPoweredFlyBehavior = new TextOutputFlyBehavior("I am flying with a rocket!")

// a user-provided behavior:
BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in) );
System.out.println("Enter text for your custom duck: ");
FlyBehavior customFlyBehavior = new TextOutputFlyBehavior( userInput.readLine() );

// creating the ducks using these behaviors
Duck propellerDuck = new Duck( propellerFlyBehavior );
Duck rocketDuck = new Duck( rocketPoweredFlyBehavior);
Duck customDuck = new Duck( customFlyBehavior);

// when behavior strategies are immutable like this one, they can be reused
Duck propellerDuck2 = new Duck( propellerFlyBehavior );
Duck propellerDuck3 = new Duck( propellerFlyBehavior );
```

Comment: So maybe, I could instead of making `FlyWithWings` and `FlyNoWay` behaviors as classes I should I make only the `TextOutputFlyBehavior` class and then store the two first in a database and load them at runtime?

Comment: @Math yes, you could do that. When you want to implement more different strategy classes, you could implement some which take the same kind of data but use it differently, like a `MessageBoxFlyBehavior` or a `TextToAudioFlyBehavior`.

Comment: Instead of a behavior interface so, I could create a `List<>` of behaviors in the Duck class, make the behavior a concrete class and load the behaviors programmatically? Sure it wouldn't fit our Duck example anymore, but I'm not developing a Duck app anyway. Maybe my example was not the best :/

Comment: @Math the NoWayFlyBehavior class could not take any data and implement the fly-method as a no-op: `public void fly() {};` - that's called a "[Null Object](http://www.oodesign.com/null-object-pattern.html)".

Comment: Thanks for your help, it helped me to have more ideas to solve my problem.